# Is there any online tool to generate cross platform (including IE6) box shadows?

Tags: css, dropshadow

I want to generate drop shadows. But it is difficult to generate cross platform shadows. Is there any online tool to generate cross platform (including IE6) box shadows?

That is I want to generate following codes automatically

```
/* For IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
        /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

Comment: I like this place, no box shadow IE6 though. http://css3please.com/

Comment: Why bother tagging this [html5][css3] if you're looking for IE6 support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the easiest task. You could try [this nice generator for crossbrowser css3](http://css3please.com/) and for IE try [this nice Framework](http://css3pie.com/).

CSS Pie makes use of Internet-Explorers Capability to enhance CSS dynamically via .htc files and their proprietary VML-Format to emulate css3. It's pretty easy to setup and works quite nicely.

Some css3 stuff also can be achieved via MS-filters.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use CSS3 PIE...it's by far the easiest method. You can just use CSS3 `box-shadow` like normal and PIE will take care of it for IE automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a generator, but I know you can partially emulate this with MS-filters.  I did find an [article](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/) that goes into this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's more of a pain to do it this way, but you could always use images.  That may be best way to get them in IE 6.  According to http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp, only 1% of Internet users use IE6 as a web browser.  You could make a separate style sheet just for IE6 so it won't clutter your main sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate css drop shadow for older IEs I'll recommend Microsoft's own tool to generate drop-shadows here is link. http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/Shadow.htm

I don't know specific online tool to generate for all browsers, but it pretty easy to do on you own
here is example for cross browser css drop-shadow

```
#box {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
       -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);  /* Firefox 4-15 */
         -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

    /* IE6 & 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=135,strength=6);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=135,strength=3)";
}
```

I hope this helps